# Retrieve resolution of an uploaded image using ImageResizer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image-resizing, imageresizer

Does [ImageResizer.Net](http://imageresizing.net/docs) for asp.net have any method by which we can know the resolution of any uploaded Image. I know one method:

```
ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.LoadImageInfo (object source, IEnumerable< string > requestedInfo )
```

that gives me Height, Width, Mimetype & extension of image file, but I have a requirement where I need to validate the resolution of an uploaded image.

Comment: Resolution is WIDTH X HEIGHT. Doesn't it?

Comment: Is that so? I need it in dpi? Minimum resolution allowed is 96 dpi.

Comment: Images have a `dpi` metadata field, but it is NEVER accurate and ignored by all programs and printers.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know dpi is something what connected to devices where images will be rendered.

So, if it is Desktop dpi can be or 72 (MAC) or 96 (Windows), but if you will print it dpi can be 150 or 300.

So to check if image will be correctly printed (with good quality) on paper  with size 200x200 milimeters you can calculate min size if image you need in pixels.

So, we have the following input:
 - dpi of printing is 150
 - size of paper is 200x200 milimeters

200 mm is 7.9 inch

=> min resolution of image should be 7.9*150 = **1185 pixels**

So only images with height and width equal or more than **1185** will be printed with good quality.

So question for you - what for you need resolution(dpi) check?

Answer (score 0):

As far as you have **Height** and **Width** you can calculate DPI using this formula:

```
dp = sqrt(width^2 + height^2)  (Pythagorean theorem)
```

then, you should know size of the screen in inches (di). Simply:

```
dpi = dp / di
```

Comment: I don't think so. Most of the images are commonly of 96dpi, if you check the properties of the image. With different image height and width the dpi value will be abnormal. Can you please cross check with any image at your end?